# InputStream, OutputStream possible memory leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I am working on a Spring Boot app that copies files from an SFTP server to an S3 bucket daily. The code works, but when I had the code run in a cloud foundry, the memory and disk usage increased, which is normal since there was about 1GB of files. The problem is that after the job completed, the increased memory/disk was still being used. It did not drop back down afterwards. I want to know if I am not closing or clearing anything correctly after the file copy to S3.

```java
Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> files = sftpChannel.ls("*.csv");
if (files.size() != 0) {
try {
    for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry file : files) {
        String fileName = file.getFilename();
        InputStream inputStream = sftpChannel.get(fileName);
        String newName = stamp + "_" + fileName;
            final File tempFile = File.createTempFile("stream2file", "tmp");
            tempFile.deleteOnExit();
            try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
                IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
                s3bucket.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("TEST", newName, tempFile));
                inputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();
                outputStream.flush();
            }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "File Not Found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "IO Exception");
        } finally {
                channel.disconnect();
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Channel Disconnected");
                session.disconnect();
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Session Disconnected");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by “PCF”?

Comment: What and where are `channel` and `session`?

Comment: "inputStream" might not close if any exception happens. It is best to close "inputStream" in "finally" clause.

Comment: Depending on the Java version, the garbage collector used, and the configuration of the garbage collector, a Java process may not return memory to the OS, even if it actually doesn't need it any more. This not a memory leak, the process just holds onto the memory in the expectation it will need it again later. Your code also doesn't seem to delete the tempFile, so no wonder it sticks around. I do have to wonder why you're even creating a temporary file, and not just streaming the input stream directly to S3.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Didn't know it is possible to use inputstream directly into the bucket. My thing I do have to rename the files before moving them but the content inside remains the same. If this will work and I can still rename the file, this would be an ideal solution. Do you have an example of inputstream directly to s3?

Comment: @BasilBourque PCF is a cloud foundry

Comment: @Stone Good point, will make that change, however when it was tested, I did not get any errors but still a good idea to change it

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with the S3 API, but a look at the AWS Java SDK v2, suggests the `TransferManager` supports it using an `UploadRequest`. Your code seems to use the v1 SDK though.

Answer (score 0):

You check with below given few suggestions

1. Make sure to close all resources that you open, not just input and output streams. Also, remember to close SFTPChannel and Session objects when you're done using them.
2. Don't keep any references to the files after copying them to S3. This can cause increased memory usage.
3. Use a tool like VisualVM or YourKit to find any objects or resources that aren't being released properly. These tools can help identify memory leaks.
4. Check if the memory usage issue persists when running the app on different environments. If it does, then it may be an issue with the code.
5. Consider using Apache Commons VFS or Spring Integration libraries to simplify the SFTP-to-S3 file transfer process. These libraries provide higher-level abstractions and handle resource management more efficiently.

I hope these will help you